# is there is way to decode a string in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, phpmyadmin

im looking to take backup of my database to use in new website but there is crypted column i want way to decrypt it before back up of mysql so i can use freely in the new website
here is my encryption code

```
function __encode($unencoded,$key = 'i have the key'){
        $string=base64_encode($unencoded);
        $newstr = '';
        $arr=array();
        $x=0;
        while ($x++< strlen($string)) {
            $arr[$x-1] = md5(md5($key.$string[$x-1]).$key);
            $newstr = $newstr.$arr[$x-1][3].$arr[$x-1][6].$arr[$x-1][1].$arr[$x-1][2];
        }
        return $newstr;
```

and here is my decryption code

```
function __decode($encoded, $key = 'i have the key'){
        $strofsym="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM=";
        $x=0;
        while ($x++<= strlen($strofsym)-1) {
            $tmp = md5(md5($key.$strofsym[$x-1]).$key);
            $encoded = str_replace($tmp[3].$tmp[6].$tmp[1].$tmp[2], $strofsym[$x-1], $encoded);
        }
        return base64_decode($encoded);
    }
```

is there way to decode the data in phpmyadmin beffor taking backup or software i can use on the backup to decrypt the data to use in the new site
thanks

Comment: @ADyson I think you misread the code! md5 is used to generate the values replacing the original characters as opposed to hashing the original text.

Comment: @Shadow hi thanks for the comment so is it possible ?

Comment: phpmyadmin is just a GUI for mysql, so your question really is: is it possible to replicate your decode method via mysql. Well, you can attempt to write a stored function that can decrypt your data with the right keys - the building blocks are there (char_length(), md5(), replace(), from_base64()).

Comment: any idea about the command i use or software i use.  i have the right keys

Comment: It's not a command you need to use. You need to write a function in mysql that replicates what your php code does. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: @Shadow can you do it i can pay you in bitcoin ?

Comment: There are sites on the Internet where you can contract programmers for short jobs. SO is not such a site.